# SQLite memory database eager loading entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I've switched our tests to use a SQLite `:memory:` database over a database file in an effort to speed up our tests.  Everything has gone smoothly, except for one caveat: it's automatically eagerly loading navigation properties on entities.

If I run the project and hit it with Postman using an actual database file, it doesn't eagerly load them, and only loads navigation properties if I specify I want them using `.Include()`.

It didn't do this before I switched to a SQLite Memory database for the tests.

The DbContext configuration is as follows:

```
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: if EF previously loaded navigation properties eagerly without the use of .Include(), there's something seriously wrong there, it shouldn't do that. Maybe you meant lazily loading navigation properties? I'm not quite sure how SQLite handles that in this case.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yeah sorry that's my mistake, it should say that it's suddenly eagerly loading, it wasn't before.

Comment: are you sure it's eagerly loading? what does the IQueryable look like, and what is the generated sql?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I can't think what else it could be doing.  All the navigation properties are loaded as soon as I retrieve an entity.  When I run the app and hit an endpoint with postman, the properties are `null` unless I specially use `Include` to get them.  When I inspect the Queryable collection before doing the retrieve, the SQL is the same!

Comment: can you give an example queryable+sql? I can't see how you can distinguish between lazy and eager loading without sql profiling (as the navigation property will be filled with lazy loading - at least in connected scenario - as soon as you inspect the object or property)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro The SQL doesn't specify any other tables, only the table of the entity to retrieve.  If I set `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`, it still has the navigation properties loaded.  The only thing I can think of is that because everything is in memory already, it's just attaching them regardless.

Comment: if the sql doesn't retrieve the objects, they are lazily loaded later, or the context already has them, which would point to a too long dbcontext lifetime.

Comment: The DbContext lifetime is actually pretty short as a new one is created each time it's requested via the TinyIoCContainer.  I had issues where after a request was completed, the context would get disposed and so I couldn't perform another request.  The connection, however, is kept open during the lifetime of the test so that the memory database doesn't get closed and data lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old post, but I thought I'd provide an answer for anyone else that stumbles upon this.

What is likely happening here is simply that your DbContext has the entities cached in its ChangeTracker.  Regardless of the underlying provider, when you insert an entity into the database, Entity Framework tracks that entity.  If you query for an entity you just inserted, Entity Framework assumes the entity would not have changed and therefore returns the entity from the ChangeTracker.  If you changed your query to do a `_myDbContext.Set<SomeEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToList()` then you should find that it performs a query and only prefetches related entities you've specified.

Comment: This works!  I'm a bit worried that it's a code smell due to having code there that just satisfies the tests, however I think for now I'll have to live with it.

Comment: Prudent use of AsNoTracking() can result in performance gains in your application, but I wouldn't recommend its use in general.  The change I suggested was just a way to confirm that SqLite was indeed working as expected.  You shouldn't use it on any queries returning entities you intend to modify.  As for solutions to the issue for testing, unfortunately Entity Framework doesn't make it particularly easy for those forgoing ORM abstractions.  It would have been nice if this setting could be controlled at the dbContext level.